# How can I create a consolidated list of Office 365 tasks (Exchange, Sharepoint, and Groups)

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

It appears that office 365 has had the My Tasks page removed from the News Feed (previously at https://CompanyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/UserName_CompanyName_onmicrosoft_com/AllTasks.aspx) As a result there is no place to get a consolidated view of tasks. As of July, 2016 there are three types of Office 365 tasks:

1. Exchange / Outlook tasks. These are accessible via the interface using the Tasks tile that takes you to https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=contoso.com&exsvurl=1&ll-cc=1033&modurl=3
2. Groups tasks that are reachable via the Planner tile at the URL https://tasks.office.com/?auth_pvr=OrgId&auth_upn=user@contoso.com&mkt=en-US.  You can view them grouped by Project (Group) or consolidated.
3. Sharepoint tasks that are reachable by going to an individual sharepoint site, finding the task list, and looking for tasks assigned to you.  I understand that there is a way to "Connect with Outlook" but that does not show online, it seems to only show in desktop Outlook.  The tasks are also undiscoverable in Delve.

I am attempting to find a way to create a consolidated view of all three types of tasks.  The first two types are discoverable in the various Microsoft Graph and Office APIs:

1. Exchange / Outlook tasks can be queried via https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/task-rest-operations#GetTasks.
2. Groups / Planner tasks are available via https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/tasks.

Unfortunately, I cannot find an API that seems to make Sharepoint tasks available.  There do seem to be some desktop DLLs available, but I'm not sure if they work with SharePoint online (maybe only on-premises?).

So, does anyone know of any way to get Sharepoint tasks assigned to a given user out of Office 365?  Alternatively, is there a third-party application that can do this already?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SharePoint Search REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx) with

```
ContentClass="STS_ListItem_Tasks"
```

in the query.